# Plotting a large graph in igraph

Tags: python, plot, igraph

I created a Graph using the igraph package (http://hal.elte.hu/~nepusz/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html), and I'm trying to plot it using the `Plot()` function. My graph has ~20000 Vertices and ~30000 Edges, and I'm struggling to find a way to plot it such that it looks remotely presentable.

Distributive Recursive Layout gives decent results, but it doesn't make much sense since vertices are arbitrarily grouped together. Fiddling with the vertex,label,edge sizes doesn't help much either.

Could someone, who has experience with plots of this size, suggest a suitable layout to data of this size?